Concentration bound for weighted sum of Bernoullis
$\{X_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Define
$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i$$
where $a_i>0$ are known(non-random) constants. I want an upper bound on the following probability
$$\mathbb{P}(|Y-\mathbb{E}Y| > \varepsilon).$$
Remarks:

I am looking for a bound of the form $k\exp(\cdot)$ for some constant $k>0$.
Using McDiarmid's inequality, I can get such a bound, but the bound does not depend on $p$. For my use case, $p$ is extremely small and it is of interest how the bound can be tightened by making it depend on $p$.
I suspect that the bound will involve $\|a\|_{\infty}$ or $\|a\|_2$ or both. For what it is worth, it is easier for me to handle $\|a\|_2$ later. However, please post your answer even if it involves $\|a\|_\infty$ or any other norm.

Any help will be super appreciated!

What would the argument of "$\exp$" be?  Why wouldn't a simple, well-known inequality like Chebyshev's suffice?  You seem to be leaving out some important background information.

For example with McDiarmid's inequality, the bound is $2\exp\left(\dfrac{-2\varepsilon^2}{|a|_2^2} \right)$. This is the form of the bound I meant. To answer the other question, the probability in question is a conditional probability conditioned on knowing $a_i$'s. Unconditionally, $a_i$'s are $\chi^2_1$ random variables in the original problem. So if I use Chebyshev's inequality, the variance in the numerator of the bound would be too large with increasing $n$.

Bernstein's inequality will involve both the 2-norm and the $\infty$-norm, but it should be good for small $p$.
